# Is there a way to download a file from a website and upload it directly to Google Drive?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, google-drive-api, webbot

I am developing a python script that downloads some files from that website. Is there a way to download and upload them directly to google drive with the API?

This is the snipet that download the file:

```
def download(): #sólo para fichero de oferta 

from webbot import Browser
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url='www.myweb.com'
web=Browser()
web.go_to(url)

web.click(xpath='/html/body/div[2]/div/div/button')
web.type('myusername', into='idUsuario', id='Usuario')
web.type('password' , into='password' , id='password') #specific selection
web.click(tag='Entrar', xpath='//*[@id="enter-button"]/a') 


time.sleep(3)

web.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="NavSeleccionApl"]/ul/li[6]/a').click()

time.sleep(1)
web.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="formContent:tablaPlantillasPorPerfil:2:j_id710"]/span').click()

try:
    time.sleep(30)
    web.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="formContent:j_id197"]').click()

except:
    print('try again')
```

and this is the one that uploads my downloaded file from my computer:

```
def adrive():



import datetime
path=r'C:\Users\myself'

print('Uploading to Drive..')
now = datetime.datetime.now()
file_name=f'file_{"_"+str(now.day) + "_"+str(now.month)+ "_"+str(now.year)}.xlsx'
file_to_up=os.path.join(file_name, path)

headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer myauthcode"} #auth code
para = {
    "name": file_name,
    "parents":["1KPrqoChDo6ZL"] #folder in drive
    }
files = {
    'data': ('metadata', json.dumps(para), 'application/json; charset=UTF-8'),
    'file': open(file_to_up, "rb")
    }
r = requests.post(
    "https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v3/files?uploadType=multipart",
    headers=headers,
    files=files
    )

print('Subido a Drive')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not wrong, you have already saved the file, you need to just upload it. Now, you had used `google-driver-api` tag so, this answer is how to use it:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file']
def upload_files():
    """
    Creates a folder and upload a file to it
    """
    # authenticate account
    service = get_gdrive_service()
    # folder details we want to make
    folder_metadata = {
        "name": "TestFolder",
        "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.folder"
    }
    # create the folder
    file = service.files().create(body=folder_metadata, fields="id").execute()
    # get the folder id
    folder_id = file.get("id")
    print("Folder ID:", folder_id)
    # upload a file text file
    # first, define file metadata, such as the name and the parent folder ID
    file_metadata = {
        "name": "test.txt",
        "parents": [folder_id]
    }
    # upload
    media = MediaFileUpload("test.txt", resumable=True)
    file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media, fields='id').execute()
    print("File created, id:", file.get("id"))
```

You may visit [here](https://www.thepythoncode.com/article/using-google-drive--api-in-python) for more/detail information. [This](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) will also be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but what I meant is if there was direct way to save the file downloaded from the website to Drive (without storing it locally first). The final goal is to schedule the script in the cloud with no need to have my laptop on.

Comment: I don't think so, cuz downloading is done by the browser and we can't make browser save automatically save in drive

Comment: But we can do some trick, if you run this program in [`colab`](https://colab.research.google.com/) there you may do these kind of things